# Air pollution index calculator

Tags: python

I got this question as an assignment:
An Air Pollutant Index (API) recording system should allow user to enter the name of month to start using the system. If the user entered September, April, June, or November as the month, 30 API readings should be keyed-in by the user into the program. If user entered February, the system will ask the user to choose between leap year or non-leap year. If user choose non leap year, 28 API readings should be keyed-in into the system or else, 29 API readings will be captured. Other than that, 31 readings should be keyed-in by the user. For each API reading entered, the program should be able to analyze the condition and display the API reading with its status as per in Figure 1.

Here's what I have tried and I can't figure it out anymore, please help;
'''

```
def index_calculator():
    month = input("What month would you like to check?: ")
    api_input_30 = []
    api_input_31 = []
    api_input_29 = []
    api_input_28 = []
    api_input = [[api_input_30], [api_input_31], [api_input_29], [api_input_28]]
    if month == "september, sept, april, june, november, nov":
        api_input_30 = [int(input("api") for _ in range(30))]
        
    if month == "feb, february":
        leap_nleap = input("Type L for leap year and N for not leap year: ")
        if leap_nleap == "L":
            api_input_29 = [int(input("api")for _ in range(29))]
        elif leap_nleap == "N":
            api_input_28 = [int(input("api")for _ in range(28))]

    if month == "jan, january, mar, march, may, jul, july, august, aug, october, oct, dec, december":
        api_input_31 = [int(input("api") for _ in range(31))]
    
    for api in api_input:
        if api >= 0 and api <= 50:
            return "Good"
        if api > 50 and api <= 100:
            return "Moderate"
        if api > 100 and api <= 200:
            return "Unhealthy"
        if api > 200 and api <= 300:
            return "Very Unhealthy"
        else:
            return "Hazardous"
index_calculator()
'''
What month would you like to check?: nov
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [37], in <cell line: 32>()
     30         else:
     31             return "Hazardous"
---> 32 index_calculator()

Input In [37], in index_calculator()
     19     api_input_31 = [int(input("api") for _ in range(31))]
     21 for api in api_input:
---> 22     if api >= 0 and api <= 50:
     23         return "Good"
     24     if api > 50 and api <= 100:

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: It would be better if you could show us examples of this lists: api_input_30 = [], api_input_31 = [], api_input_29 = [], api_input_28 = []. And are you whant to use this code api_input = [[api_input_30], [api_input_31], [api_input_29], [api_input_28]] exept this api_input = [api_input_30, api_input_31, api_input_29, api_input_28]?

Comment: the lists are supposed to have different integers inputed by the user

Comment: How you want to work with lists of numbers? Because in your loop it will wor only with the first number in list and will return the result. If you whant to return results to every number, you should create a list of results and then return this list. Or may be you want to use another algorithm?

Comment: I tweaked it a bit and came up with something that sorta works

Answer (score 1):

> for api in api_input:
> if api >= 0 and api <= 50:
> return "Good"

api is an element of api_input. In your code api_input contains lists for e.g. api_input_30 is a list, therefore each instance 'api' is actually a list and you can't compare a list to an integer as the TypeError says.

Comment: Is there a way to access the elements of the nested lists?

Comment: You could use a nested for loop but  the best practice would be to not have your month elements in a nested list

Answer (score 0):

```
def index_calculator():
    month = input("What month would you like to check?: ")
    days = int(input("How many days are in this month?: "))
    leap_nleap = (input("Type L for leap year and N for non-leap year: "))
    api_input = [int(input("api: ")) for _ in range(days)]
    
    if leap_nleap == "L":
        days = 29
    elif leap_nleap == "N":
        days = 28
    
    for api in api_input:
        if api >= 0 and api <= 50:
            print("Good")
        elif api > 50 and api <= 100:
            print ("Moderate")
        elif api > 100 and api <= 200:
            print ("Unhealthy")
        elif api > 200 and api <= 300:
            print ("Very Unhealthy")
        else:
            print ("Hazardous")
index_calculator()
```

I came up with this code, It kinda works to solve the problem.